# JPA Criteria: build specification matching any id in collection

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to build a query via JPA CriteriaBuilder to find all objects having their id in a list of given values.

This is what I created:

```
protected <T> Specification<T> equalsToAnyId(Set<Long> ids) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> builder.or(root.getModel().getDeclaredSingularAttributes().stream()
                .filter(a -> Collections.singletonList("id").contains(a.getName()))
                .map(a -> builder.in(
                        root.get(a.getName())).value(ids))
                .toArray(Predicate[]::new)
        );
    }
```

This does not seem to match any record (empty result set). What's wrong with it?

Comment: care to share what JPQL that equates to, and what SQL is executed?

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a very convoluted way to write a simple IN filter. Unless you are writing some kind of DAO framework, why accept `root, builder, query` and return `Specification` when the whole query takes only few lines?

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<T> cq = cb.createQuery(entityClass);
Root<T> root = cq.from(entityClass);
cq.where(root.get("id").in(guids));
return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

If you want to keep your method signature, then just do:

```
protected <T> Specification<T> equalsToAnyId(Set<Long> ids) {
    return (root, query, builder) ->  builder.or(builder.in(root.get("id")).value(ids));
}
```

Although you did not specify what `Specification` is(There is no such class in JPA spec).

In general, if you are not sure why your query does not return the data you expect, turn on the SQL logging, either via provider specific property in `persistence.xml`, e.g. `hibernate.show_sql` for hibernate, or by enabling debug/fine logging of your persistence provider, e.g. `org.hibernate.SQL`

As a side note: yes we are all happy that java finally has lambdas, but that does not mean we have to lambda all the things:) Especially the way how you stream/filter/map the metamodel just to get `root.get("id")` ... strikes me as odd.

Comment: [Specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/reference/jpa/specifications.html)